# How to remove text and make the corresponding element an empty tag using `lxml`?

Tags: python, lxml

I wanted to make my XML document more data-centric.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| original input | `<elem>1</elem>` |
| desired output | `<elem value="1"/>` |

Idea:

```py
for elem in doc.xpath("//elem"):
    elem.attrib["value"] = elem.text
    elem.text = ''
```

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| the above code gives | `<elem value="1"></elem>` |

What to do to reach the desired output, i.e. an empty tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `None` instead of the empty string as the `text` value.

```py
for elem in doc.xpath("//elem"):
    elem.attrib["value"] = elem.text
    elem.text = None
```